# Checking for equal bounds in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I'm following the official PostGIS Introduction (https://www.postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/equality.html) and struggling on Chapter 22.1.3. The author want to compare the bounding boxes of different polygons with `=` to check if the extents are equal. Unfortunately running the code from the website doesn't give me expected result as in the training excercise.

Here's the code from the Introduction:

```
CREATE TABLE polygons (id integer, name varchar, poly geometry);

INSERT INTO polygons VALUES
  (1, 'Polygon 1', 'POLYGON((-1 1.732,1 1.732,2 0,1 -1.732,
      -1 -1.732,-2 0,-1 1.732))'),
  (2, 'Polygon 2', 'POLYGON((-1 1.732,-2 0,-1 -1.732,1 -1.732,
      2 0,1 1.732,-1 1.732))'),
  (3, 'Polygon 3', 'POLYGON((1 -1.732,2 0,1 1.732,-1 1.732,
      -2 0,-1 -1.732,1 -1.732))'),
  (4, 'Polygon 4', 'POLYGON((-1 1.732,0 1.732, 1 1.732,1.5 0.866,
      2 0,1.5 -0.866,1 -1.732,0 -1.732,-1 -1.732,-1.5 -0.866,
      -2 0,-1.5 0.866,-1 1.732))'),
  (5, 'Polygon 5', 'POLYGON((-2 -1.732,2 -1.732,2 1.732,
      -2 1.732,-2 -1.732))');

SELECT a.name, b.name, CASE WHEN a.poly = b.poly
    THEN 'Equal Bounds' ELSE 'Non-equal Bounds' end
  FROM polygons as a, polygons as b LIMIT 10;
```

My Output:

```
"Polygon 1";"Polygon 1";"Equal Bounds"
"Polygon 1";"Polygon 2";"Non-equal Bounds"
"Polygon 1";"Polygon 3";"Non-equal Bounds"
"Polygon 1";"Polygon 4";"Non-equal Bounds"
"Polygon 1";"Polygon 5";"Non-equal Bounds"
"Polygon 2";"Polygon 1";"Non-equal Bounds"
"Polygon 2";"Polygon 2";"Equal Bounds"
"Polygon 2";"Polygon 3";"Non-equal Bounds"
"Polygon 2";"Polygon 4";"Non-equal Bounds"
"Polygon 2";"Polygon 5";"Non-equal Bounds"
```

Output from the tutorial:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I compare the bounding boxes of a collection of polygons in a table?

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4.26 with PostGIS 2.5.1 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The workshop is outdated.

The [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Geometry_EQ.html) says

> The = operator returns TRUE if the coordinates and coordinate order
>   geometry/geography A are the same as the coordinates and coordinate
>   order of geometry/geography B.
>
> Changed: 2.4.0, in prior versions this was bounding box equality not a
>   geometric equality. If you need bounding box equality, use [~=](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Geometry_Same.html)
>   instead.